# How to parse Facebook Page status in javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/
there is no option for Facebook Status parse.

for example https://www.facebook.com/adidas , how can I parse the top status of this page in my website.

Please Help, Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mean the "parse" method in this respect, if I understand you correctly you want to use the api to display the status on your site? Parse is used for rendering xfbml tags on the fly. For the status you'd want to use the api calls such as FB.api
For this you will need to set-up an app and use the access_token to make a request to

https://graph.facebook.com/adidas/posts

Public info (without an access_token) can be accessed at https://graph.facebook.com/adidas

more info on the javascript api is available here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/